# How do I create a EtcdCluster in Kubernetes

Tags: etcd3

Etcd-operator (v0.5.1) examples have files with `kind: "EtcdCluster"`.

```
apiVersion: "etcd.database.coreos.com/v1beta2"
kind: "EtcdCluster"
metadata:
  name: "example-etcd-cluster-with-backup"
spec:
  size: 3
  version: "3.1.8"
  backup:
    # short snapshot interval for testing, do not use this in production!
    backupIntervalInSecond: 30
    maxBackups: 5
    storageType: "PersistentVolume"
    pv:
      volumeSizeInMB: 512
```

[source](https://github.com/coreos/etcd-operator/blob/master/example/example-etcd-cluster-with-backup.yaml)

How do I create such a kind, in Kubernetes?

The etcd-operator documentation doesn't seem to cover this, and they don't seem to have a dedicated mailing list (otherwise, I'd posted this question there).

Comment: Don't link to third party sites to show what you want. Your link can die in an hour and no one will know what you're talking about. Post it here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Corrected. Referred file now copied here.

Comment: You can deploy etcd on each host and create a cluster that way.  You can find more documentation on CoreOS site.